# Left joining based on a combination of columns in a range of columns

Tags: r, left-join

I have two tables. In table A I have 36 columns that can be empty or contain a specific product. In table B I have all kinds of combinations of products and an ID per combination (all combinations contain 2 products, such as the following table).

| ID | Product | recommendation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | productrec. 1 |
| 2 | 1 | productrec. 2 |
| 3 | 1 | productrec. 3 |
| 4 | 2 | productrec. 1 |
| 5 | 2 | productrec. 2 |
| 6 | 2 | productrec. 3 |

I want to join this ID in all the rows of table A that have an corresponding combination of products. The challenge is, however, that the first product of the combination can be in the first column, but the other product of the combination can be in any other column (so not necessarily adjacent).

How would I be able to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You need to provide example data about both table a and table b